# Java Loop question about !scanner.nextLine() as condition

Tags: java, loops

I'm learning to code Java with mooc at the moment and am doing an assignment where you take user input (and do stuff with it). The program/loop ends if user inputs nothing and enters.

So this is the right answer which I did correctly:

```java
while (true) {
    String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
    if (sentence.equals("")) {
        break;
    }
}
```

However before this I also tried something like:

```java
while (!scanner.nextLine().equals("")) { // ...
```

Why does that method not work? I don't see anything wrong with it.
(Below is the whole code if needed)

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AVClub {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!scanner.nextLine().equals("")) {
            String sentence = scanner.nextLine();

            String[] array = splitter(sentence);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i].contains("av")) {
                    System.out.println(array[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static String[] splitter(String sentence) {
        String[] array = sentence.split(" ");
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `scanner.hasNext()` ?

Comment: Please read my edited post for clarification on why your code doesn't work. :)

Comment: Oh I think I get what you mean by running the scanner twice now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `scanner.hasNext()` to see if there is anything else that you can read in. Instead of your splitter method, you can use `StringTokenizer` which will tokenize the String by spaces.

The reason your code does not work is because you are calling Scanner.nextLine() twice. Even though your code:

`while (!scanner.nextLine().equals(""))`

is a condition check, it reads it in and moves on. Think about it like this: The Scanner is like a book reader. When you call Scanner.nextLine(), the book reader moves to that line and reads it. When you called it again, it read an empty line. For example, if I input this:

[image: first]

Your reader will read in the "I like pie" and check to see that it is not a "". When it is done, and you get your `sentence` variable, you called the method again, which reads in the NEXT line, which is not there. So your code fails to work.

Comment: Thanks that works, but was there any reason why the code I tried didn't work? I can't seem to think of anything that was off (assuming Enter is the only thing I press in an attempt to end the program)